# How to debug a React.js/Django-Rest-Framework application in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

How can I do debugging in VS Code for React.js/Django-Rest-Framework Application.

I'm to do debugging in solo django application but When I use react as frontend, it not stop at breakpoint.